# query cannot be enumerated more than once

Tags: linq, c#-3.0

I want to do the following

```
var totalNoOfRows = result.First().TotalNumberOfCount;
```

And finally do something like that

```
bookssList.AddRange(retResult.Select(r => r.ToBook()));
```

where ToBook is extended method

but I always get The result of a query cannot be enumerated more than once.

```
if (result != null)
                            {

    var totalNoOfRows = result.First().TotalNumberOfCount;
                                pagingContext.ItemsTotal = totalNoOfRows != null ? int.Parse(totalNoOfRows.ToString()) : 0;
                                var retResult = result.ToList();
                               // pagingContext.ItemsTotal = totalcount.Value != null ? int.Parse(totalcount.Value.ToString()) : 0;
                                                                    bookssList.AddRange(retResult.Select(r => r.ToBook()));
                            }
```

Comment: Huh? More code please. I don't see how the two snippets have **ANYTHING** to do with each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to guess what are you doing, and how these snippets relate to each other, but if you can enumerate a collection only once, then call `ToArray` first:

```
var resultCopy = result.ToArray();

//... any number of operations on resultCopy
```

Note that calling `First` also counts as enumerating. So you need to enumerate and copy the collection even before this.

Comment: No, he's not. Event after the edit, he first calls "First", and then "ToList".

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the code to this, so you only enumerate `result` once:

```
var retResult = result.ToList();
var totalNoOfRows = retResult.First().TotalNumberOfCount;  //You are now using LINQ on the list, not the query!
pagingContext.ItemsTotal = totalNoOfRows != null ? int.Parse(totalNoOfRows.ToString()) : 0;
                               // pagingContext.ItemsTotal = totalcount.Value != null ? int.Parse(totalcount.Value.ToString()) : 0;
Logger.LogInfo("Search Payments GetPaymentsWithCount stored procedure result not null and count=" + totalcount);
bookssList.AddRange(retResult.Select(r => r.ToBook()));
```